# Tag rename request : [gameboy-color] -> [game-boy-color]

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, tag-rename-request

I recently created [gameboy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameboy-color) and it seams that I went wrong, the tag should be [game-boy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy-color) like [game-boy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy) or [game-boy-advance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy-advance).

Renaming/making synonym the tag could also be a good occasion to make [gbc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gbc) synonym before someone use it.

Answer (score 8):

I deleted the [gameboy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameboy-color) tag from your question, rather than retagging. Platform tags are only for questions *specifically about the platform*. Do not add them to questions that are about games that happen to be on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no need to make a tag synonym.  The [gameboy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameboy-color) tag has only one question (yours), and there are no questions tagged [game-boy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy-color).  Remove the [gameboy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameboy-color) tag from your question and add [game-boy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy-color).  The [gameboy-color](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameboy-color) tag will automatically be deleted since there will be no questions tagged with it.

I now see that this is not possible due to a feature that prevents users from accidentally creating new tags from typos.  Moderator intervention may be required.  I would mod flag on your question explaining the situation.

Comment: Tried it, but [tag:gameboy-color] have not been deleted, even if I saved edit. Could not add [tag:game-boy-color] because [tag:gameboy-color] already exist, even if there is no question tagged with it.

Comment: I tried too.  Got the following error: *You are attempting to create the tag [game-boy-color]; however the tag [gameboy-color] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta*

Comment: Interesting, must be a feature exclusive to Gaming.SE.  This must require mod intervention.  I'd mod flag on your question @Jouramie.

Comment: @JAL It's not an exclusive feature, and it has been around for a while now. It's to prevent people accidentally creating new tags from typos